# Path & Compilation issue | Texmaker MikteX

Tags: miktex, texmaker, paths, miktex2.9

I've just installed MiKTeX and TeXMaker on my PC (previously worked on Overleaf which is fine until you have to write a whole master thesis).

I have trouble while trying to compile a document, cf. screenshot below
[image]

After some preliminary research, it seems that it might be related to my MiKTeX installation and more precisely the paths. Indeed, MiKTeX signals an issue (cf. 2nd screenshot below)
[image]

This is where I'm a bit lost. I've seen different solutions on different forums; 
1) By modifying the MiKTeX Console -> Settings -> Directories but I don't know exactly how 
2) By modifying the PATH environment variable on my PC but again I don't know exactly how. Plus, it seems that the correct path is already there (cf. screenshot below, apologies for the interface language in french). 
[image]

There is obviously something that I don't understand. Does anyone have an answer/ an idea to solve the problem ? Would be great !

Thanks in advance.
Rodolphe

PS. Working on Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9, Texmaker 5.2. I've only tried Quick Build.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have any reason not to install MiKTeX for every user of the computer?

Comment: Not immediately familiar with Texmaker, but in TeXworks provided by MiKTeX, you need to use `%1.tex` to refer to the first argument, not `%.tex`.  So, the `pdflatex` call should look like `pdflatex -syntex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1.tex`.  It seems this is likely a TeXmaker setting that needs updating?

Comment: Hi. No, I'm the only user of the computer. How can I change the installation / How can it be useful ? Thanks for your swift answer!

Comment: Hi @whatisit. I've tried your solution. It doesn't seem to solve the situation, unfortunately,as the error message is now "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1.tex"

Comment: If you install MiKTeX for every user (even if you're the only user really), it will be in `C:\ Program Files`, which is part of the path. Desure to reinstall TeXmaker *after* you've reinstalled MiKTeX. Personally, I have no problem with this installation (under Windows 7 Pro).

Comment: @Bernard I did not install MiKTeX for every user, I only install it for me. All the files now go to `C:\Users\<name of the user>\...`. However, I can still compile my documents normally.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested and who might have a similar problem, the solution is the following;

"If you install MiKTeX for every user (even if you're the only user really), it will be in C:\ Program Files, which is part of the path. Desure to reinstall TeXmaker after you've reinstalled MiKTeX"

Thanks @Bernard !